# How do I optimize python code without losing results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, telegram-bot

I was working on one telegram bot, and when finally I made everything I discovered that it is extremely slow.

`s()` takes 5-7 seconds to get result and send it to user, I tried to optimize it with methods from other sites, but it didn't work.

**How can I optimize it?**

```
import telebot
import pyscp
from googlesearch import search
scp = "scp-"
bot = telebot.TeleBot("NO")

def extract_arg(arg):
    return arg.split()[1:]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['o'])
def o(message):
   global status
   status = extract_arg(message.text)
   try:
    object = status[0]
   except Exception as e:
    object ="7777"
   l = scp + object
   url = "scpfoundation.net/" + l
   ru_wiki = pyscp.wikidot.Wiki('scpfoundation.net')
   p = ru_wiki(l)
   try:
    k = ('{}'.format(p.title))
    text = (f'<a href="{url}">{k}</a>')
   except Exception as e:
    text="Простите, этот номер не присвоен не одному из объектов"
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text,parse_mode='HTML')

def extract_argument(argument):
    return argument.split()[3:]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['s'])
def s(m):
    status1 = m.text
    status2 = status1.replace('/s', "")
    f = open("base.txt", "r")
    searchlines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if line.strip()]
    f.close()
    out = []
    out1=[]
    try:
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
                if status2.lower() in line.lower():
                            for l in searchlines[i : i + 1]:
                                    out.append(l.split(maxsplit=1)[0])
                                    out1.append(l.split(maxsplit=1)[1])
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Простите, не смог ничего найти.",parse_mode='HTML')
        pass
    finalout = list(set(out))
    number = len(finalout)
    g, nm, count, count1, gey =[], int("0"), int("0"), int("0"), []
    while (nm<number):
        url = 'http://scpfoundation.net/'
        try:
            ru_wiki = pyscp.wikidot.Wiki('scpfoundation.net')
            p = ru_wiki(finalout[count])
            k = ('{}'.format(p.title))
            gey.append(k)
            result = " ".join ([url, finalout[count]])
            g.append(f'<a href="{result}">{k}</a>')
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        count+=1
        count1+=1
        nm+=1
    numbeer=int('0')
    counter=int('0')
    ka = search(f'{status2} site:scpfoundation.net', num_results=4)
    while (numbeer<5):
        try:
            ru_wiki = pyscp.wikidot.Wiki('scpfoundation.net')
            p = ru_wiki(ka[counter])
            kj = ('{}'.format(p.title))
            if (kj not in gey and "forum" not in ka[counter] and "draft" not in ka[counter] and "fragment" not in ka[counter]):
                    result = ka[counter]
                    g.append(f'<a href="{result}">{kj}</a>')
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        numbeer+=1
        counter+=1
    story = '\n'.join(g)
    try:
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, story,parse_mode='HTML')
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Простите, ничего не найдено.", parse_mode='HTML')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help(t):
    bot.send_message(t.chat.id, "/o — поиск по номеру; /s — поиск по названию; /help — это сообщение; /join — присоеденится к сообществу; /faq — ответы на частые вопросы",parse_mode='HTML')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['join'])
def join(j):
    joiner=(f'<a href="http://scpfoundation.net/system:join">Подай простую заявку!</a>')
    bot.send_message(j.chat.id, joiner,parse_mode='HTML')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['faq'])
def faq(f):
    faqer=(f'<a href="http://scpfoundation.net/faq">Читать тут.</a>')
    bot.send_message(f.chat.id, faqer,parse_mode='HTML')
bot.polling()
```

The problem is with `while (numbeer<5)`.

5 is number of urls I grab from google search, and less urls I grab less times it need.

I can't reduce the numbers of urls, so maybe  can optimize another part of code to reduce the time?

Comment: Hi, you could try to post it on Code Review too: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your question is so specific and provides so match code I recon that only person who gets paid for this will help you. When you are asking a question it is here not only for you but also for others.  Read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues, but I'm guessing that the major slowdown in `s()` is due to the unnecessarily repeated calls to `pyscp.wikidot.Wiki('scpfoundation.net')`. This web request is done once for each match in `searchlines` and then done 5 more times again. I'm assuming this is the exact same data retrieved every time.

You should do this only once in `s()` at most in my opinion then use the saved result inside your `while` loops.

Comment: What other problem are there?